# A mapped type may not declare properties or methods - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an interface, which should have keys that are in specific enum key type, but when I declare the type it gives this error:

> A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.

Here is the code:

```
enum myEnum {
  propOne = 'propOne',
  propTwo = 'propTwo'
}

export interface myInterface {
  [key in myEnum]: anotherInterface;
}
```

I tried to specify the type also like this, but it didn't work and gave me syntax error:

```
export interface myInterface {
  [key in keyof typeof myEnum]: anotherInterface;
}
```

I also tried to use a normal object instead of an enum, but it gave the same error.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to use [Mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), not interface:

```ts
export type MyInterface = {
  [key in myEnum]: AnotherInterface;
}
```

Comment: How can I use this in combination with an interface, e.g. if my interface needs to have variable keys, as in `[key in myEnum]`

Comment: thanks, i have kind of a habit to using interface at almost everywhere.