# How to add a new property in a type that was designed like this

Tags: typescript

I would like to add a new property to a type

Right now, my type **ValidateResult**  :

```
type FieldKey = 'internal' | 'external'

export type ValidateResult = {
  [x in FieldKey]: any
}
```

However right now, I would like to add a newKey to it. But I cant add this new key to type Field, So, I did sth like below. But it throw sytax error.

```
export type ValidateResult = {
  [x in FieldKey]: any
  newKey: any
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get? And what version of `tsc` are you using?

Comment: Please show us `FieldKey` too

Comment: You are missing a `,` (comma) after the `[x in FieldKey]: any`.

Comment: @PatrickCerny , comma isnt the problem. I tried

Comment: @Dai ESLint: Parsing error: ';' expected.

Comment: @user21357723 ESLint isn't TypeScript

Comment: Disregarding ESLint, `tsc` errors-out with _"A mapped type may not declare properties or methods."_ on the same `newKey` property - which is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A mapped type may not declare properties or methods - TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652935/a-mapped-type-may-not-declare-properties-or-methods-typescript)

Comment: @PatrickCerny [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) alias syntax uses semicolons (`;`) not commas.

Comment: @Behemoth saw that afterwards, didnÄt want to delete my comment as someone already replied to it - oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I like to work with [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) when extending [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#handbook-content).

```
type FieldKey = 'internal' | 'external'

type ValidateResult = {
  [x in FieldKey]: any;
} & {
  newKey: any;
}
// type ValidateResult = {
//     internal: any;
//     external: any;
//     newKey: any;
// }
```

<sub>[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwNIRFAvFA5HAO2AgCcCBDRXKAHzwgA9izLcAoN0SKANUrmTliAJQgBnAK6Jg2KAG82UKAG0GUQrAQp0IALoAuKOQIgA3GwC%20UAGTzFUAhADuOw8bOW2Aei9Qu0PkQBIQhRSWlZBR8lGMJmCkQ3E3NomKhGeMokj1SYxxcMbJTfCyA)</sub>

However, if all properties in your object have the same value type you can use a new [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in your [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like so:

```
type FieldKey = 'internal' | 'external'

type ValidateResult = {
  [x in FieldKey | "newKey"]: any;
}
// type ValidateResult = {
//     internal: any;
//     external: any;
//     newKey: any;
// }
```

<sub>[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwNIRFAvFA5HAO2AgCcCBDRXKAHzwgA9izLcAoN0SKANUrmTliAJQgBnAK6Jg2KAG82UKAG0GUQrAQp0mOgCICEAO469AXQBcUcgRABuNgF82AehdQu0PogFCIoyWlZBTclMMJmCkQrG3tXdzCoRkjKGNsHUMTDEww0uNDHIA)</sub>

Comment: what is the difference between using | and & there?

Comment: When using an intersection type (`&`) with two object types the properties will be *merged* in one object. The other approach uses a union type (`|`) to augment `FieldKey` with `"newKey"`. I suggest taking a look at the TypeScript docs for Intersection Types and Union Types for more details but in short: `&` -> An assigned value must be assignable to all types in the intersection. `|` -> An assigned must be assignable to either types in the union. This is heavily inspired by mathematical [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a new type definition with the missing key, like so:

```
type FieldKey = 'internal' | 'external'
type ValidateResultKey = FieldKey | 'you_done_goofed'

export type ValidateResult = {
  [x in ValidateResultKey]: any
}
```

Alternatively you can use the & operator and combine it with another type if you want a different type on that

```
type FieldKey = 'internal' | 'external'

export type ValidateResult = {
  [x in FieldKey]: any;
} & {
  test: string;
}

const test = {
  internal: "",
  external: "",
  test: "",
} as ValidateResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more generic, you can extend the base type:

```
type FieldKey = 'internal' | 'external'

type ValidateResult<T extends (string | undefined) = undefined> = {
  [x in (FieldKey | T) as x extends undefined ? never : x]: any;
}

// Now you can define your custom types:

type ValidateResultWithNewField= ValidateResult<'newField'>;

// or event

type ValidateResultWithMultiNewFields = ValidateResult<'field1' | 'f2' | 'anotherField' | 'etcField'>;
```

Comment: may i ask what does undefined mean there in <T extends (string | undefined) = undefined>? How to interpret undefine here? 

[x in (FieldKey | T) as x extends undefined ? never : x] : how to interpret  extends undefined ? never : x here?

Comment: @user21357723 I use it to enable using the type without passing in keys, that is, preserving the original type.